# How to control gnome-terminal from Python script?

Tags: command-line, application-development, python, gnome-terminal, gtk

I am developing an application in PyGtk, and would like to launch a gnome-terminal and output commands to it.

My user should then be able to modify the command, or maybe ignore using the up arrow ... etc.

I have been able to launch a terminal, but can't work out how to send commands.

This is how my application starts:

```
class App(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        process=subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "--class=App", "--name=app"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        response,error=process.communicate()
```

Comment: [related Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725343/communication-between-two-gnome-terminal-sessions)

Answer (score 1):

According to the python docs, you want to use 
  `Popen.communicate(input=None)`
http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

I would recommend that you edit your command from python before sending it to another process. For example, display a window with the default command and allow the user to edit (or cancel) it before executing it. Also, "gnome-terminal" is probably overkill for this, "/bin/bash" should be sufficient.

If that doesn't work for you, you could also try this. (depending on what you are actually running from the terminal) Since you mentioned users could edit the command, it would be a good idea to validate the input before running.

```
command = ['ls','-l']
output = subprocess.check_output( command )
print( output )
```

Comment: OP is already using the suggestion via `response,error=process.communicate()` where process is an instance of `Popen`. "*Also, "gnome-terminal" is probably overkill for this, "/bin/bash" should be sufficient.*" I think OP actually deliberately wants to show the terminal in his GUI app.

Comment: You are correct @gertvdijk, I want a terminal embedded into my application. I am currently using Vte.Terminal, which is good, but it does not behave just like gnome-terminal. For example the delete key produces ^[[3~, and the up arrow key does not show the previous command. I also got excited by what I found here: "gnome-terminal --help-gtk", and figured this would do the job.

Comment: @user936401 If you did found the solution, please create a new answer.

Comment: No solution found.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Solved it with tmux, thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194293/how-to-send-terminal-command-to-a-tty-terminal) (copied below).

In the terminal that should receive the command start tmux with an identifier:

```
tmux new-session -s MYSES
```

Send commands to it with:

```
tmux send-keys -t MYSES "ls -l"$'\n'
```